How to upload locally files to Teams with visual basic code
I am having trouble uploading a locally located pdf file to teams as a different name with visual basic code.
Syncing locally doesn't upload files to Teams.
In the code below, the destURL is the part that I synchronized locally.
Sub CopyFileAndRename()

Dim srcURL As String
Dim destURL As String

srcURL = "C:\Path\To\Your\banana.pdf"

DestURL = "C:\Users\id\company"

CopyFile srcURL, destURL

End Sub

75 I get a runtime error, path file access permission error.

DestURL = "C:\Users\id\company\banana.pdf"

DestURL = "C:\Users\id\company\banana.pdf" still gives me 75 errors.

Can you copy the same file manually into that folder?

Resolved.
It was an error 75 times because of company security.
Thank you.
